# How to make java list co-variant

Tags: java, list, subclass, superclass, invariants

I have following classes

```
public class Animal


public class Dog extends Animal


public class Cat extends Animal
```

And for the testing I have a driver class.

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<? extends Animal> animalList = Arrays.<Dog>asList(new Dog(), new Dog(), new Dog());
        animalList.add(new Dog()) // Compilation error 
    }               
}
```

By default list are invariant type containers.  For example  say we have `List<Object> objectList`, `ArrayList<String> stringList` We cant substitute stringList to objList. which will cause a compilation error

My attempt is to make list co-variant as in the Driver class.

According to the `<? extends Animal>` we can apply any object that is a subtype of Animal including Animal type.

But I'm getting a compilation issue in the indicated line. Can someone explain theoretically where I went wrong.

Comment: The reason you can't do things like `add` on a wildcard-parameterised `List` is given in the Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html.

Comment: Collections are by their nature *contravariant*. It would be a mistake to make them covariant.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik afaik not true. they are neither co-, nor contravariant.

Comment: @kritzikratzi In Java they aren't; that's not my point. It is a known type-thoeretical fact that collections obey the contravariant rules.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik oh, i see what you mean... and agree :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I think the word you're looking for here is *invariant*. What makes you say that collections are contravariant? Are you looking at this in terms of reading from them or adding to them?

Comment: @seh True, that came out wrong. You need declaration-site variance (Java only has use-site variance) to make each operation behave appropriately. I had Java arrays in mind, which are covariant by design, therefore writing to them can fail even when it type-checks.

Comment: Mutable collection are invariant. Immutable collections are covariant, but altering a collection is a contravariant operation, which means a mutable collection must be invariant to support both reads and writes. A write-only "collection" would be contravariant.

Answer (score 4):

I think you misunderstand generic wildcards (`?`).  From the [Java tutorial on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html):

> There is, as usual, a price to be paid for the flexibility of using
>   wildcards. That price is that it is now illegal to write into shapes
>   in the body of the method. For instance, this is not allowed:
>
> ```
> public void addRectangle(List<? extends Shape> shapes) {
>     // Compile-time error!
>     shapes.add(0, new Rectangle());
> }
> ```
>
> You should be able to figure out why the code above is disallowed. The
>   type of the second parameter to `shapes.add()` is `? extends Shape` -- an
>   unknown subtype of `Shape`. Since we don't know what type it is, we
>   don't know if it is a supertype of `Rectangle`; it might or might not be
>   such a supertype, so it isn't safe to pass a `Rectangle` there.

Java generic collections are not covariant; see e.g. [*Java theory and practice: Generics gotchas*](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

java doesn't have a very powerful type system, which means: you can't do this.

sad answer, but true. from wikipedia:

> Unlike arrays, generic classes are neither covariant nor
>   contravariant. For example, neither `List<String>` nor `List<Object>` is a
>   subtype of the other

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Java

Comment: What does this have to do with weak typing?

Comment: sorry, bad choice of words. i meant "not very powerful".

Comment: I think Type Erasure is a good term here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: i'm honestly not sure if this is directly caused by type erasure, i can imagine that being the case, but i also guess there _could_ be some clever workarounds. it's besides the point for me though, fact is it's not possible.

Comment: @kritzikratzi yes what you have mention in your answer is right we cant assign that way because list are invariant, but my question is about making them co-variant by using wild cast

Comment: it definetley isn't because of type erasure. Scala also runs on the JVM and has type erasure, but supports both covariant and contravariant types

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<? extends Animal> animalList = Arrays.<Cat>asList(new Cat(), new Cat(), new Cat());
        animalList.add(new Dog()) // Compilation error 
    }               
}
```

and the compilation error makes a lot more sense right?  All Java has to go off of is the type you gave it for `animalList`.  Java knows that the stuff on the right side may be a list of `Cat` objects so it won't let you put in a `Dog`.  Change your code to be

```
List<Animal> animalList = Arrays.<Animal>asList(new Dog(), new Dog(), new Dog());
```

and this will work ok.

Comment: I'm trying to help make it more obvious why your original code doesn't compile.  I think most people looking at your code would think it should compile, but when you change around the runtime type it makes it much more obvious what is going on.  I'll adjust my note about changing the List type.